# Puppeteer ignores proxy setting

Tags: node.js, proxy, puppeteer

I have the following code which is almost identical with the example provided on GitHub (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/proxy.js):

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [ '--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080' ]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=a; laravel_session=b; LS_CSRF_TOKEN=c;'
  })
  try {
    await page.goto('http://localhost:8888');  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```

However, it looks like the proxy setting is ignored. Because none of the requests hits the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 `await page.goto('http://my-app:8888');`
```

and add `my-app` to your hosts file.